# Controlar "documento expirado"

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Tengo un proyecto en php creado con laravel, cuando me identifico y voy a otra página (La que sea) y le doy al botón del navegador de retroceder, me salta un " documento expirado " [image: documento expirado]

Si vas navegando entre las páginas, 3 ,4 ,5 ..... y le das al botón, irás a la página anterior , HASTA QUE la anterior sea la del inicio.

Necesito que cuando le des hacía atrás que detecte que es la de inicio y se quede en la principal del administrador porque si estás conectado no te voy a devolver a la del Login...

¿Cómo se puede hacer?

Comment: Hola, para retroceder utilizas algún botón con una función js o te refieres al botón retroceder del navegador?

Comment: el botón del navegador, cuando ya le das atrás y ese atrás era la página de logín, salta lo de documento expirado, yo quiero no poder llegar ahí que detecte que era esa página o algo por el estilo.

Comment: Podrías colocar un if con php para que cuando ya se halla iniciado sesion que te redirija a la pagina de inicio, por ejemplo: `if(isset($_SESSION['idi]))  redirect('inicio');` y de esa forma ya no te aparece esa pantalla.

Comment: pero eso solo se ejecuta en lado servidor, si tú le das a retroceder en el navegador, está tirando de la caché del lado cliente.