# Problema al retroceder al momento de loguearse (Laravel 5.2 php)

Tags: php, laravel

He creado un login en Laravel 5.2 pero tiene un problema al momento de loguearme me redirecciona al panel de admin (hasta ahi to bien) pero cuando presiona la flecha de retroceder del navegador me aparece el campo email lleno (por ejm: henry@gmail.com y el campo password vacio) y luego presiono el boton de siguiente del navegador y me redirige al panel de admin. Quisiera que eso no pase..sino al momento de retroceder el login este vacio ni me redirija al panel de admin sin antes loguearme. Estoy usando la clase Session para el login.

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');
Route::post('login','AdminController@ingresarSession');
Route::get('logout','AdminController@cerrarSession');
```

AdminController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use DB;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use App\Http\Requests\UserFormRequest;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('login.login');
    }

    public function ingresarSession(Request $request)
    {
        $email=$request->input('email');
        $password=$request->input('contrasena');

        $user=DB::table('users')->where("email","=",$email)->where("contrasena","=",$password)->get();

        if($user>0)
        {
            Session::put('email',$email);

            return Redirect::to("ventas/venta");
        }else{
            return Redirect::to("/");
        }
    }

    public function cerrarSession()
    {
        Session::forget('email');

        return Redirect::to("/");

    }
}
```

login.blade.php

```
<head>
    <title>Ventasoft</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('img/favicon.ico') }}">
</head>

<body background="{{ asset('imagenes/login/fondo.jpg') }}">

@if(count($errors)>0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{$error}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

<div class="container" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-12" style="background: #fff;margin-top: 50px;">
            <h1 class="text-center">Acceso al Sistema</h1>
                <img class="center-block" src="{{ asset('imagenes/login/usuario.png') }}" width="180px" height="180px">
                <br/>
                {!! Form::open(array('method'=>'POST','action'=>'AdminController@ingresarSession')) !!}

                {{ Session::forget('email') }}
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
                <br/>
                <input type="password" name="contrasena" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                <br/>

                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Ingresar</button>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

el Middleware Admin.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
class Admin
{
    protected $auth;
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth=$auth;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->session()->has('email'))
        {
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            return redirect()->to('/');
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, esa es una pregunta muy complicada, ya antes han hecho una pregunta semejante sin éxito [Controlar documento expirado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155771/controlar-documento-expirado?noredirect=1#comment292754_155771), en caso de no haber una respuesta alguien debería ofrecer una recompensa.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un grupo de rutas que tengan como atributo tu middleware Admin:

```
Route::middleware(['admin'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');
});
```

O sólo asignar el middleware a una ruta especifica:

```
Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->middleware('admin');
```

Pero recuerda que primero debes registrar el middleware en el kernel de la app, en el archivo `app\Http\Kernel.php` y  en la propiedad `$routeMiddleware` lo agregas, ejemplo:

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
```

También note que dices que al presionar la flecha de retroceder del navegador vuelves al login, y luego presionas el botón de siguiente del navegador y te redirige al panel de admin, al hacerlo de esa forma en ningún momento estas cerrando la sesión del usuario por lo tanto éste continua logueado.